# Wordpress Kirki: Typo found in field post_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I hosted a wordpress site in a cloud hosting. I notice apache `error_log` file size growing very fast and I found this error (`Kirki: Typo found in field post_title ("setting" instead of "settings")`) from `error_log` file.

I google this error and I didn't get any good answers.

Comment: Usually, error logs have pointers to file where the error happens...

Comment: No details in error log. only show ``[Wed Apr 26 00:04:26.334382 2017] [:error] [pid 12559:tid 140623738763008] [client **.***.**.***:56556] Kirki: Typo found in field post_title ("setting" instead of "settings").`` this error

Comment: Same case for me. I can confirm that there are no pointers mentioned to file.

Comment: I solved this issue with commenting that line. I didn't notice any other problem with this. I will give you details

Comment: File name ``class-kirki-field.php`` Line : 287,  File location ``wp-content/themes/theme-name/core/kirki/includes`` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I found the same thing in a site, though in this case it was in `wp-content/themes/theme/inc/customizer.php` at line 587.

Commenting out a line might have unintended side effects.

Given the nature of the error and looking at code on other lines it does seem to be a typo.  Changing `setting` to `settings` seems to have solved the problem.